# Return 2 rows from 2nd table INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 2 tables, crm_lead and statussen.

This is (part of) content table statussen

```
stat_id   | stat_type       | stat_naam 
1         |   lead_status   |   Ingevoerd CJV     
2         |   lead_status   |   Ingevoerd website
...       |   ...           |   ...    
11        |   lead_bron     |   Zelf gegenereerd
12        |   lead_bron     |   Bestaande klant
```

In lead i've 1 column "lead_status" and "lead_bron". Both have the id of the corresponding row from table statussen.

When I run following query:

```
SELECT * FROM crm_lead
INNER JOIN statussen on crm_lead.lead_status=statussen.stat_id
WHERE lead_id=31
```

The result is only showing one row of table statussen (lead_status) and not lead_bron...

I get the single row from table crm_lead with lead_status = 1 and lead_bron = 11. But I also get only 1 row from table statussen: stat_id = 1. But I also need the row with stat_id = 11 from that table..

Comment: Edit your question and provide more complete sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are searching for only lead_status and not lead_bron (in your join).

This is one way to get what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    crm_lead
    INNER JOIN statussen ON crm_lead.lead_status=statussen.stat_id
WHERE lead_id=31

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
    crm_lead
    INNER JOIN statussen ON crm_lead.lead_bron=statussen.stat_id
WHERE lead_id=31
```

Comment: Ok, it's working in PHPMyAdmin. But how can I echo it in PHP?

Comment: I don't know much PHP, but if you post how you are doing this with your current SQL, I can probably suggest something.